# How to setup nginx reverse proxy from a root domain in to specific path in another domain?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, virtualhost, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have successfully setup virtual hosts in nginx so that I can access the website with two domains. What I'd like to do is to forward ***domain2.com*** to ***domain1.com/test*** but without redirecting it to ***domain2.com/test***. My current virtual host configuration for ***domain2.com*** looks like this:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;

   server_name domain2.com www.domain2.com;

   location / {
    proxy_pass http://domain1.com/test;
    }
}
```

But when accessing ***domain2.com***, I'm redirected to ***domain1.com/test***.

> #### In short, I'd like to access ***domain1.com/test*** under ***domain2.com***.

Comment: First, add a trailing `/` on your `proxy_pass` statement to make the aliasing work correctly. If the problem persists, use `curl` to identify the exact value of the `Location` header in the 3xx response from the server.

Comment: Okay, when I access domain2.com, I am redirected (301) to domain1.com/test/. What I want is to have domain2.com in the browser address bar after redirect.